# wordpress count rows that are same in custom table

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a custom table within my wordpress database. I would like to COUNT the rows in the table that have the same value.

So for example:

IP ADDRESS

0.0.0.0.0

0.0.0.0.1

0.0.0.0.0

The output would then be:

there are 2 x 0.0.0.0.0

there are 1 x 0.0.0.0.1

I can achieve the above fine with a normal sql query, but i am trying to do this via the $wpdb class

Here is my query:

```
$table =  $wpdb->prefix . 'wplt';

$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ip_address, COUNT(ip_address) FROM $table GROUP BY ip_address");

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

    echo $post->ip_address;

    echo $post->COUNT(ip_address);

}
```

With the above i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::COUNT()

Comment: `var_dump($post)` normally shows you more. You likely mean `$post->{'COUNT(ip_address)'};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error you are getting because `$post` object doesn't has any count function

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::COUNT()
```

If you want to show the count of ip address from query you can assign an  alias to that count in the query like

```
$table =  $wpdb->prefix . 'wplt';

$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ip_address, COUNT(ip_address) AS ip_count FROM $table GROUP BY ip_address");

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

    echo $post->ip_address;

    echo $post->ip_count ;

}
```